# copy excel cells and send the same with format via mail to some user

Tags: c#, excel, smtp

I want to know how to send copied cells of an excel worksheet via mail to some user. It should display in the body part with all the formatting that is present in the worksheet(colors,borders etc.). I can manually copy the cells and paste it in the body section as it looks in the worksheet. But the same I am not able to do via code using c#. Here is the code that I ve written so far

```
        destPath = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\AZL6I76\\Desktop\\FIXED Aging incident       Report.xls";
        destxlApp = new Excel.Application();
        destworkBook = destxlApp.Workbooks.Open(destPath,0,false);
        destworkSheet = destworkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        destrange = destworkSheet.UsedRange;
        string s = srcrange.get_AddressLocal(false, false, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        int p1=s.IndexOf(':');
        s=s.Substring(p1+1);

        destrange=destworkSheet.Range["D6:"+s];

        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.domain.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("Harry@domain.com");
            mail.To.Add("Harry@domain.com");
            mail.Subject = "IFO Report";
            mail.Body = "Dear All,\n\nThis email is to report the statistics with different status as on " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".\n\n\n";
            mail.Body+=destrange.value2;
            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            SmtpServer.Port = 25;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
```

The excel copied data is not at all getting displayed in the body of the mail. I am using the Lotus Notes mail system.

Comment: You have in your code `mail.Body += destrange.value2;` but after a quick look at [Range.Value2 Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2(v=office.15).aspx) shows that it returns an object type.  So perhaps it might be safer to call `mail.Body += destrange.value2.ToString();`.

Comment: @Ben I tried it but still it is not displaying the excel data instead System.Object[,] gets displayed in the mail body.

Comment: This indicates that `destrange` contains a 2D array of objects.  (Presumably each object is a cell).  How about looping through your cells in the range and add them to the email body one at a time?

Comment: Wouldn't your MailMessage be text without setting the `IsBodyHtml` property? I've done before sending HTML from Excel in email - the code came from here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519602(v=office.11).aspx#odc_office_UseExcelObjectModeltoSendMailPart2_CreatingHTML (Creating HTML for a Worksheet, Range, or Selection)] but it is in VBA...

Comment: @Captain Could you please post the code in c# as I am not getting the required result.

Comment: @Harry I am afraid that I have only done it in VBA...